# Identity Inspector Not showing Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am new to IOS  I want to link my viewcontroller to swift file..But for me **show the identity inspector** option is not showing...

please find screen shot below

[image]

> please any one tell me how to link my swift file to my viewcontroller
>   or how to find **show the identity inspector options**

2.I am not able to link my class custom class dropdown is empty

[image]

Comment: you must need to create a  UITabBarController file for this

Comment: Oh ok sir...how to created that UITabBarController...please help sir..I am new..I seen one video based I am developing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the last button in your Xcode

[image]

[image]

You need to subClass it here
[image]

Comment: Happy Coding :D

Comment: just select the storyboard and click on the double circle icon ;D

Comment: ok sir..take your time please update your answer..waiting for your update...Note For me custom class dropdown showing empty it was not listing swift clas..

Comment: Happy Coding again :D

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can click it right here, you will see the tap